# drawing shapes on UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to draw shapes like tiangle, circle and rectangle with CGContext on UIImageView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Draw lines on UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680855/draw-a-line-in-uiimageview-problem)

[Tutorial for drawing other shapes](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/ipad-development/draw-circle-triangle-and-rectangle-in-iphone/)

[CGContext Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html)